# Storing md file at the root of the react website folder affect the performance of the website

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I want to store .md files inside a folder called some_readme_files at the root of the react app folder but I'm not importing these files anywhere in my code. These files are just for reference.
Each file has some text and 2-3 images. I want to know does it affect the performance of the react app.

.md file text look something like this.

```
Challenge Title
A clear challenge title.

Challenge Description
A clear and concise description of the challenge.

Difficulty Level
Challenge difficulty level. (i.e. Beginner, Intermediate, Hard)

Tags
Tags relevant to the challenge. (i.e. FRONTEND, BACKEND, FULL-STACK, and MOBILE)

Design Images
Provide images of the design files for both Desktop and Mobile.

Learning
A clear and concise description of what they'll learn after completing this challenge.

Requirements
A clear and concise requirements to complete this challenge. (i.e. User can toggle between Light and Dark mode)
Write requirements in bullet points

Additional information
Add any other information about the challenge.
```

Anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it's worst when you do not import/use it.

The deployment can be a bit slower, because you have a few files to download.

For example, in the React source, they have many markdown files. The CHANGELOG.md is quite big, but it's not bad, even it's gives you more information.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Actually, I am planning to take new challenges from the community member, so, I decided to take it through the .md file so, it would be easier for them to contribute new challenges using the above template in the form on .md file, they just need to add a new file for a new challenge.

is there any better way to do this?

Comment: It should be work , just try it. The other ways are ask them to create issues for their challenge on gitlab, discuss on it, then implement or do what ever you want later.